# Not getting all the values in model class with Firestore Paging Adapter?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore ui for pagination to load data into my recycle view.
In my model class, only two fields are getting value and rest are remaining null. What's the problem?

Just the 'imgUrl' and 'createTime' is having values and rest of all are null.
I have tried to use use a custom SnapshotParser. but thats also doesnt solve my problem.

```
Query baseQuery = Ref.orderBy("createTime");

PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(10)
                .setPageSize(8)
                .build();
FirestorePagingOptions<NewsItem> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<NewsItem>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(baseQuery, config, NewsItem.class)
                .build();

        newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(options);


//My model class class


public class NewsItem {
    private String Headline;
    private String Description;
    private String Author;
    private String AuthorId;
    private String id;
    private String imgUrl;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date createTime;



    public NewsItem() {
    }

    public NewsItem(String Headline, String Description, String Author, String AuthorId, String imgUrl) {
        this.Headline = Headline;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.Author = Author;
        this.AuthorId = AuthorId;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;

    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return Headline;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }

    public String getAuthorId() {
        return AuthorId;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public Date getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        Headline = headline;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        Author = author;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(String authorId) {
        AuthorId = authorId;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us the content of your `NewsItem` class.

Comment: Firstore keys should match property names in your `NewsItem`, also read java naming convention

Answer (score 0):

I should have used the proper java naming convention. 'Headline' is storing as 'headline' in firestore. All the other variables are converting automatically the same away. Making all the variable camelcase solved my problem.